# Matrix multiplication $AB=0$ so $A=0 $ or $B=0$

Tags: matrix-equations, transpose

I have tried with the idea of $AA^T=0 $ and use the trace, but nothing changed.

I have also to prove : if $AB=0 $ then $BA=0$ .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Neither the statement in the title nor the statement in the body are true in general.

Comment: Yeah i have to prove that its not true, i will change the statement

Comment: If $AB=0$ then either $A=0$ or $B=0$ or $|A|=0\ and\ |B|=0$. And any of these conditions implies $BA=0$ as well

Comment: @LoopBack Not true, there are counterexamples.

Comment: Actually your statement is right only for $1$ -square matrices... ie the real numbers...

Answer (score 0):

The ring of square matrices is not integral  i.e if $AB=0$ then it is not necessary that one of them is the zero matrix.

take for example:
$$
   A= \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & z \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

and

$$
   B= \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

This example also shows (for $z\neq0$) that if $AB=0$ then it does not mean necessarilly that $BA=0$ .

Comment: Sorry, may you use other tecnique? The book im using just showed the basic properties. But thanks for the answered already showed

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa Your comment about "other tecnique" is difficult for me to understand. The only technique used in dmitri's answer is matrix multiplication, which you surely know because it's the basis for your question.

Comment: The moment he says "the ring of square matrices", i mean. The other part ive understood perfectly

Comment: Don't worry about the ring part now if you haven't learnt about that. Just focus on the counterexample shown by dmtri.

Comment: Thanks everyone